# Python - get request developer tools mimic returns different HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, http-headers, get-request

I am sending a get request with python to a php-script:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("someurl/somemore/smth.php")
```

I noticed that the returned HTML is not the same I expected (the HTML I saw in my browser) so I looked in the Firefox Developer Tools and wrote down the excat same parameters I found there in the headers:

```
headers = {"A awful lot of stuff":"stuff",...}
```

But still I am not getting the expected HTML. There is a "Cookie"-Parameter which is Session specific (PHPSESSID) so I modified that paramter as follows:

```
Cookie: "PHPSESSID="+session.cookies.get_dict()["PHPSESSID"]
```

That seems to work fine but I am still getting a different HTML.
Why is that? What other differences are there in the browser's interpretation and how can I emulate them in python (using requests, not selenium)
Thank you folks

Appendix:
The code I recieve with my script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     top.location.href = "logout.php";
</script>
```

The original, uninterpreted HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html id="MapFrameID1">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Map</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        p,ul,ol,td,span,
        layer,table,body    { font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #222222; }
        p                   { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        a:link { color:#CC3300; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; }
        a:visited { color:#CC3300; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; }
        a:active { color:#FF3300; text-decoration:hover; font-weight:bold; }
        a:hover  { color:#FF3300; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; }
        h1 { font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom: 0px;}
        .medium { font-size:11px; }
        .small { font-size:10px; }
        .framemapbg { margin: 10px; margin-top: 3px; }
        p.positiontext { background-color: #BBBBBB; border: 1px solid #555555; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; width: 100%; }
            a.nocango:hover:after { content: ""; position: absolute; bottom: .25em; right: .25em; background: white; border: 0 solid red; border-width: .28em .12em; width: .56em; height: .24em; cursor: default; }
            a:focus { outline:0; -moz-outline:0; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function stopErrors() {
        return true;
    }
    window.onerror = stopErrors;

    var target="test";
    var timer;
    function countdown()
    {
        millisekunden = ende - new Date().getTime();
        text = Math.ceil(millisekunden / 1000);
        x = document.getElementById(target);
        if(millisekunden > 0)
            text2 = 'Du kannst in ' + (text/60>=1?Math.floor(text/60)+' Minuten und ':'')+(text%60) + ' Sekunden weiterreisen';
        else
            text2 = '';
        x.innerHTML = text2;
        if (millisekunden<=0)
            window.clearInterval(timer);
    }

    function refreshtravel(newtravel)
    {
        if(newtravel > 1)
        {
            var oldwielang = ende - new Date().getTime();
            ende = newtravel * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
            if(oldwielang<=0)
            {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    countdown();
                    timer = window.setInterval("countdown()", 1000);
                }, ende % 1000);
                countdown();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(ende - new Date().getTime() > 1000)
                ende = 0;
        }
    }

    function Move(dirx, diry)
    {
        if(ende - new Date().getTime() <= 1000)
        {
            location.href = 'map.php?walkX=' + dirx + '&walkY=' + diry + '&intwalkid=574928190';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" class="framemapbg">
<script language="JavaScript">
var mainForm = parent.frames.mainFrame.formular, itemFrame = parent.frames.itemFrame;
if (parent.frames.reloadChatFrame.active_websocket == false)
{
    parent.frames.chattextFrame.location.href = 'chattext.php';
    if(mainForm && (mainForm.block_reload.value != 'true' || (mainForm.block_reload_pos && mainForm.block_reload_pos.value != '104|100')))
    {
        parent.frames.mainFrame.location.href = 'main.php';
    }
}
if(itemFrame && itemFrame.formular && itemFrame.formular.block_reload.value != 'true')
{
    parent.frames.itemFrame.location.href = 'item.php';
}

var tele = parent.frames.chatformFrame.document.chatform.tele;
var group = parent.frames.chatformFrame.document.chatform.group;

if (tele)
{
    tele.style.display = 'none';
    tele.removeAttribute('accesskey');
}
if (group)
{
    group.style.display = 'none';
    group.removeAttribute('accesskey');
}
</script>
    <div align="center">
        <p class="positiontext"><a href="map.php?&reload=1"><img src="../images/relmap.gif" align="top" border=0></a> Position X: 104 Y: 100</p>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
            a.nocango  { background: #transparent; height: 100%; width: 100%; border-width: 0; display: block; }
        .mapstate { -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
        .maptable, .maptable * { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
    <table class="maptable" width="250" height="250" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" data-mapsize="5"><tr><td id="mapx102y98" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx103y98" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx104y98" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx105y98" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx106y98" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td></tr><tr><td id="mapx102y99" style="background-image:url(../images/map/wasserfall.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: default;"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Nordwesten</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Nordwesten"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx103y99" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(-1, -1);" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx104y99" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(0, -1);" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx105y99" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(1, -1);" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx106y99" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td></tr><tr><td id="mapx102y100" style="background-image:url(../images/map/wiese2.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: default;"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Westen</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Westen"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx103y100" style="background-image:url(../images/map/akademie2.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(-1, 0);" ><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Westen</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Westen"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx104y100" style="background-image:url(../images/map/wies7.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(0, 0);" ><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc></desc><path class="user" d="M 17 21 L 21 17 L 25 21 L 29 17 L 33 21 L 29 25 L 33 29 L 29 33 L 25 29 L 21 33 L 17 29 L 21 25 Z" stroke="red" fill="white" /></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/user.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt=""><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx105y100" style="background-image:url(../images/map/wies8.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(1, 0);" ><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Osten</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Osten"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx106y100" style="background-image:url(../images/map/wies11.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: default;"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Osten</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Osten"><![endif]--></a></td></tr><tr><td id="mapx102y101" style="background-image:url(../images/map/wiese3.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: default;"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Südwesten</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Südwesten"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx103y101" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(-1, 1);" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx104y101" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(0, 1);" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx105y101" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" onClick="javascript:Move(1, 1);" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx106y101" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td></tr><tr><td id="mapx102y102" style="background-image:url(../images/map/forest3.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;" class="maptd"><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: default;"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"><desc>Südwesten</desc></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Südwesten"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx103y102" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx104y102" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx105y102" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td><td id="mapx106y102" style="background-image:url(../images/map/std.jpg); background-size: 50px 50px; position: relative;;" class="stdjpg"><a style="text-decoration: none;" class="nocango"><!--[if !IE]>--><svg width='50' height='50' class="mapstate"></svg><!--<![endif]--><!--[if IE]><img src="../images/map/zahl0.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0"><![endif]--></a></td></tr></table>
<div id="test" align="center" class="small"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ende = new Date().getTime() + -3240600;
    setTimeout(function() {
       countdown();
       timer = window.setInterval("countdown()", 1000);
    }, ende % 1000);
    countdown();
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.body.background = '../images/itembg.jpg';
</script>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="1" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast1').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="2" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast2').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="3" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast3').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="4" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast4').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="5" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast5').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="6" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast6').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="7" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast7').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="8" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast8').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="9" onClick="parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('accessfast9').click(); parent.itemFrame.focus();"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="button" accesskey="i" onClick="var search = parent.itemFrame.document.getElementById('searcht'); if (search) { search.value = ''; search.focus(); parent.document.getElementById('searchsave').value = ''; } else { parent.itemFrame.location.href = 'item.php?action=openinv'; }"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you posted both versions of the HTML that you are seeing.

Comment: I added the html recieve with my script and the uninterpreted html